# Negative derivative

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

If f is a differentiable function on R such that f(−x) = −f(x), for all x ∈ R, then could you explain why f′(−x)=f′(x) ?? An example would be so helpful! Thank you!

Comment: It's just the chain rule. The derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $g'(x)f'(g(x))$. Take the case where $g(x)$ is $-x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Try the chain rule, with $g(x) = -x$.

Comment: Then wouldn't it become -f′(−x) ??

Comment: @Emily Would it? Why do you think it should?

Comment: @Emily if $f'(-x) = -f'(-x)$ then $f'(x) = 0$ so that's surely wrong. I assume you're confusing $f'(-x)$ and $\Big(f(-x)\Big)'$.

Comment: Wow! yes! thank you!!